# problem with the romberg method in scipy.integrate

Tags: python, scipy

I'm running the following script with anaconda (scipy 1.10.0)

'''

```
from math import cos, pi
from scipy.integrate import romberg

f = lambda x: x**2*cos(x)**2

res = romberg(f, -pi/2, pi/2)

print(res)

res = romberg(f, 0, pi/2)

print(res)

dx = 1e-4
res = romberg(f, -pi/2+dx, pi/2)

print(res)
'''
```

It prints the following results:

```
    '''
    9.687909744833307e-33
    0.25326501581059374
    0.5065300316142199
'''
```

The result should be 0.5065300316211875.
It seem to me that scipy.integrate.romberg has problem with the lower integration limit pi/2.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Kind Regards
Klaus

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You are just unlucky: your function happens to be 0 (well, very close to 0) at the ends and the midpoint of the interval [-pi/2, pi/2].  This fools the [Romberg method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg%27s_method) into "thinking" that the error estimate is small enough to stop iterating after just three function evaluations.

```
In [52]: import numpy as np

In [53]: from scipy.integrate import romberg

In [54]: def f(x):
    ...:     return x**2 * np.cos(x)**2
    ...: 

In [55]: f(np.array([-np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2]))
Out[55]: array([9.25127234e-33, 0.00000000e+00, 9.25127234e-33])

In [56]: romberg(f, -np.pi/2, np.pi/2, show=True)
Romberg integration of <function vectorize1.<locals>.vfunc at 0x13c783b50> from [-1.5707963267948966, 1.5707963267948966]

 Steps  StepSize   Results
     1  3.141593  0.000000 
     2  1.570796  0.000000  0.000000 

The final result is 9.687909744833307e-33 after 3 function evaluations.
Out[56]: 9.687909744833307e-33
```

A work-around for this particular example is to lower the absolute tolerance parameter `tol` to something tiny:

```
In [57]: romberg(f, -np.pi/2, np.pi/2, show=True, tol=1e-36)
Romberg integration of <function vectorize1.<locals>.vfunc at 0x13bedc790> from [-1.5707963267948966, 1.5707963267948966]

 Steps  StepSize   Results
     1  3.141593  0.000000 
     2  1.570796  0.000000  0.000000 
     4  0.785398  0.484473  0.645964  0.689028 
     8  0.392699  0.505254  0.512181  0.503262  0.500313 
    16  0.196350  0.506452  0.506851  0.506496  0.506547  0.506572 
    32  0.098175  0.506525  0.506550  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530 
    64  0.049087  0.506530  0.506531  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530 
   128  0.024544  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530  0.506530 

The final result is 0.5065300316150426 after 129 function evaluations.
Out[57]: 0.5065300316150426
```

That gives a value close to what you expected.